# GStreamer Python Fails on Restart

Tags: python, gstreamer

### I have an error where the code below works fine the first time I run it but after I kill the process and try it again, new_sample is never called and no data is received despite the creating the pipeline and starting a main loop successfully.

In order to actually get it to run again, I have to restart my computer. I think it must be something related to cleaning up the gstreamer pipeline but I have already tried numerous things and I can't find the gstreamer process in ps aux for the life of me. Also, I should mention that if I run gst-launch-1.0 with the equivalent pipeline, it works every time. I think the problem is specific to the python implementation.

```
def new_sample(appsink):
    sample = appsink.emit('pull-sample')
    print "pull sample"
    buffer = sample.get_buffer()
    print "got buffer"
    data = buffer.extract_dup(0, buffer.get_size())
    save_image(data)
    return False

'''
 gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=YOUR-PI-IP-ADDRESS port=5000  ! gdpdepay  ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
'''
def start_consume(ip=DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS, port=DEFAULT_PORT):
    global pipeline

    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    tcpsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('tcpclientsrc','tcpsrc')
    tcpsrc.set_property("host", ip)
    tcpsrc.set_property("port", port)

    gdepay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('gdpdepay', 'gdepay')

    rdepay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtph264depay', 'rdepay')

    avdec = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avdec_h264', 'avdec')

    vidconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'vidconvert')

    asink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('appsink', 'asink')
    asink.set_property('sync', False)
    asink.set_property('emit-signals', True)
    asink.set_property('drop', True)
    asink.connect('new-sample', new_sample)
    asink.connect('pull-sample', pull_sample)
    asink.connect('pull-preroll', pull_preroll)

    pipeline.add(tcpsrc)
    pipeline.add(gdepay)
    pipeline.add(rdepay)
    pipeline.add(avdec)
    pipeline.add(vidconvert)
    pipeline.add(asink)

    tcpsrc.link(gdepay)
    gdepay.link(rdepay)
    rdepay.link(avdec)
    avdec.link(vidconvert)
    vidconvert.link(asink)
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    return pipeline

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        loop = GObject.MainLoop()
        pipeline = start_consume()
        loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Closing pipeline"
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        loop.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the error was closing the gstreamer pipeline. Closing with control + \ works while closing with control + c doesn't.